# Passing a pointer to an object with an initializer list, into another objects ctor

Tags: c++

I am writing an example of the object adapter design pattern. Here is my adaptee class

```
class Adaptee
{
public:
    Adaptee(Coord x1, Coord y1, Coord x2, Coord y2)
    {
        x1_ = x1;
        y1_ = y1;
        x2_ = x2;
        y2_ = y2;
        std::cout << "LegacyRectangle:  create.  (" << x1_ << "," << y1_ << ") => ("
            << x2_ << "," << y2_ << ")" << std::endl;
    }


    void oldDraw()
    {
        std::cout << "LegacyRectangle:  oldDraw.  (" << x1_ << "," << y1_ <<
            ") => (" << x2_ << "," << y2_ << ")" << std::endl;
    }
private:
    Coord x1_;
    Coord y1_;
    Coord x2_;
    Coord y2_;
};
```

In my adapter class I pass a pointer of Adaptee to the constructor, and I declare an Adaptee pointer field in my private data area. The problem is I am confused about how to include Adaptee's initialiser list in Adapters ctor. Here is my attempt

```
class Adapter : public Target
{
public:
    Adapter(Adaptee* adaptee) : _adaptee(adaptee)
    {
        std::cout << "RectangleAdapter: create.  (" << _adaptee->x1_ << "," << y <<
            "), width = " << w << ", height = " << h << std::endl;
    }

    virtual void draw()
    {
        std::cout << "RectangleAdapter: draw." << std::endl;
        oldDraw();
    }

private:
    Adaptee* _adaptee;
};
```

Comment: What do you mean by "include initializer list in ctor"? You don't need the parameter for Adaptee in Adapter. you have to create an instance of Adaptee before passing it to Adapter. And while creation you need the parameters for Adaptee: `Adapter my_adapt(new Adaptee(0,0,1,1));`

Comment: `_adaptee->x1_` is not possible, its `private` member, you have to implement `get()` function

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding something but as far as I know an initializer list is for initializing objects but if you pass a pointer of an already initialized object you can assign the pointer in the constructor body.

Comment: It would be better if less time is spent playing buzzword bingo, and throwing around PHB-compliant words like "design pattern", and such, and more time spent reading a good C++ book to learn the fundamental principals of the C++ language, like what it means to construct an object.